# Incompatibility between unixODBC and Firebird ODBC driver

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, firebird, r, unixodbc

I'm currently developing a application based in Rcode, ODBC and Firebird.

For that, first I've installed firebird server and unixODBC (both 64 bits since my machine OS is 64-bits). I tried with 32-bits software aswell since Ubuntu multiarch allow it, but that caused another problem (doesnt matter in this subject).

Created database, using firebird isql function (/opt/firebird/bin/isql), and made some fake tables with integer, float, text columns.

I can connect to it using unixODBC isql function (after properly programming DSN and Driver in odbc.ini / odbcinst.ini), but theres a problem:

**I can't select tables containing text columns, it gives error std::bad_alloc**

After some research, I've discovered *slencheck* function from unixODBC, using it on my driver returns

```
slencheck: sizeof(SQLLEN) == 4
slencheck: driver manager and driver differ!!!
```

**How can I modify unixODBC SQLLEN so it became compatible with 64-bits Firebird ODBC driver**?

I can't select text columns because of SQLLEN or there's more to this?
I think this [odbc's github issue](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/71) is related to mine

Comment: I'd recommend asking on the firebird-odbc-devel mailing list (subscribe on https://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/lists/firebird-odbc-devel or by sending an email to firebird-odbc-devel-request@lists.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Getting support from firebird group helped, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came to a solution, if anyone is interested:

For any reason, firebird ODBC 64-bits driver downloaded from oficial site comes with SQLLEN = 4 bytes. After some [help](https://www.mail-archive.com/firebird-support@yahoogroups.com/msg20295.html), I managed to compile driver from [source code](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird-odbc-driver), and the result seems to work with 8 bytes SQLLEN.

In the compile proccess, I had a BUILD_DRIVER_VERSION error, modifying line 139 (SetupAttributes.h), [adding spaces between each number](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird-odbc-driver/pull/2/commits/a112c15b912473174d9295e4d32c97cc27604830) fixed it.